# Interpreting t 'arulesSequences' Results in R

Tags: r

I used a 'arulesSequences' in R to analyze the user's sequence of actions.

And I got results like this

```
'#' | sequence | support
1   | <{A,B}>   |  0.87
2   | <{A},{B}> |  0.68
```

They seem to be the same sequence. What's the difference?

Does this mean that session has changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence 1 means that A and B happened together at the same time. The sequence 2 means that first A happened, then B happened